# How convert list of dictionaries to a dictionary of dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am trying to merge in just one dictionary a group of dictionaries, following the example.

I have a list of dictionaries:

```
dict_list = [ {'key1':1, 'key2': 2, ...}, {'key1':1, 'key2': 2, ...}, {'key1':1, 'key2': 2, ...} ... ]
```

And I would like to convert it to:

```
dictonary = { {'key1':1, 'key2':2, ...}, {'key1':1, 'key2':2, ...}, {'key1':1, 'key2':2, ...} ... }
```

Does anyone know if it's possible?

Comment: you would need a key for each dictionary in your dictionary. Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: Your output appears to be a set of dictionaries which, as dictionaries aren't hashable, isn't possible.

Comment: I could create a new dictionary using a primary key, for each dictionary. So, it's not possible create dictionary of dictionaries without primary key for each dictionary?

Comment: @JoanNadalBrotat why do you want a dict with no key

Comment: correct. lets say you just keyed it numerically it would look like `dictonary = { 1: {'key1':1, 'key2':2, ...}, 2: {'key1':1, 'key2':2, ...}, 3: {'key1':1, 'key2':2, ...} ... }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could change the keys to whatever you want but as an example you could do

```
dict_list = [ {'key1':1, 'key2': 2}, {'key1':1, 'key2': 2}, {'key1':1, 'key2': 2}]
dictionary = {}
for i, d in enumerate(dict_list):
    dictionary[i] = d

{0: {'key2': 2, 'key1': 1}, 1: {'key2': 2, 'key1': 1}, 2: {'key2': 2, 'key1': 1}}
```

As a note this isn't very useful since you can just search your list by index which is the same syntax as getting your value based off your key. The only way it would be different is if your keys weren't based off something like peoples names

```
print dictionary[0]
{'key2': 2, 'key1': 1}

print dict_list[0]
{'key2': 2, 'key1': 1}
```

Comment: Or `dictionary = {i: d for i, d in enumerate(dict_list)}`.